# NPM Script Substitution/Arguments

Tags: javascript, npm

I have an npm script:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --config build/webpack.myconfig.js"
}
```

I'd like to be able to run the command as follows to replace "myconfig" with something arbitrary:

`npm run start myOtherConfig`

and have it replace myconfig. Is there a way to do substitution like this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. But you can create as many custom commands as you want.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline",
    "myconfig": "webpack-dev-server --inline --config build/webpack.myconfig.js",
    "myotherconfig": "webpack-dev-server --inline --config build/webpack.myotherconfig.js",
}
```

And just do:
`npm run myconfig` or `npm run myotherconfig`